# Is there a Doctor anywhere on Point Lookout?

Tags: fallout-3

I have a solid addiction going on.
My character has now been drunk since I arrived on the ferry,
I'm not sure it is much of a problem, plenty of booze around.

If I am remembering Fallout 3 right, doctors can just cure addictions.
I could be wrong though it has been like 5 years since I played,
and I exitted the vault and bealined straight to the ferry and point lookout.

So far, the only merchant I have found is the "House of Wares";
which offers general stock (including Aid), and also offers repair service.
But no doctoring.

I'ld rather not pay the $450 to travel back to the mainland for medical attendion, and then pay $450 again to return to Point Lookout

Answer (score 8):

> There are no doctors in Point Lookout. The only way to heal your
>   character is through food/stimpacks and using radaway to lower your
>   radiation level. If you have an addiction, you have to go back to the
>   capital wasteland to get rid of it.

[source](http://fallout.answers.wikia.com/wiki/Finding_a_doctor_in_point_lookout)

Also found [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091207154730AACqMFR) which might be of help in the future.

> In Old Olney there is a doctor you can convince to go to point lookout